# Rewrite json object list into key value pairs

Tags: python, json, google-workspace

I am trying to format oauth token logs pulled from Google Workspace API using python. The objects returned from the google API call use a mix of formats.

Some sections are formatted like `"kind": "admin#reports#activity"`, which is preferred, while other sections are formtted like `"name": "api_name", "value": "caldav"`. How can I rewrite the sections formatted like the second example to match the first example? `"name": "api_name", "value": "caldav"` would become `"api_name" : "caldav"`.

Sample log returned (some sections have been redacted):

```
{"kind": "admin#reports#activity", "id": {"time": "2022-07-13T11:45:59.181Z", "uniqueQualifier": "<redacted>", "applicationName": "token", "customerId": "<redacted>"}, "etag": "<redacted>", "actor": {"email": "<redacted>", "profileId": "<redacted>"}, "ipAddress": "<redacted>", "events": [{"type": "auth", "name": "activity", "parameters": [{"name": "api_name", "value": "caldav"}, {"name": "method_name", "value": "caldav.calendars.report"}, {"name": "client_id", "value": "<redacted>"}, {"name": "num_response_bytes", "intValue": "165416"}, {"name": "product_bucket", "value": "CALENDAR"}, {"name": "app_name", "value": "<redacted>"}, {"name": "client_type", "value": "<redacted>"}]}]}
```

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: if you have a list of dicts with `name` and `value` keys you can use a dict comprehension to turn it into a dictionary: `converted_dict = {item["name"]: item["value"] for item in list_of_dicts}`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! 

I am getting a key error because one of the value keys is named "intValue" instead of "value". Is there a way I can do an  `item["value" or "intValue"]` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using your sample log like this.

```
import json
d = {"kind": "admin#reports#activity", "id": {"time": "2022-07-13T11:45:59.181Z", "uniqueQualifier": "<redacted>", "applicationName": "token", "customerId": "<redacted>"}, "etag": "<redacted>", "actor": {"email": "<redacted>", "profileId": "<redacted>"}, "ipAddress": "<redacted>", "events": [{"type": "auth", "name": "activity", "parameters": [{"name": "api_name", "value": "caldav"}, {"name": "method_name", "value": "caldav.calendars.report"}, {"name": "client_id", "value": "<redacted>"}, {"name": "num_response_bytes", "intValue": "165416"}, {"name": "product_bucket", "value": "CALENDAR"}, {"name": "app_name", "value": "<redacted>"}, {"name": "client_type", "value": "<redacted>"}]}]}

converted_dict = d["events"][0]["parameters"]
ans = {}
for i in converted_dict:
    ans[i['name']] =i.get('value') or i.get('intValue')
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
{'api_name': 'caldav', 'method_name': 'caldav.calendars.report', 'client_id': '<redacted>', 'num_response_bytes': '165416', 'product_bucket': 'CALENDAR', 'app_name': '<redacted>', 'client_type': '<redacted>'}
```

I hope this is what you wanted.

You can also pass two keys to find value out of python dict like this:

```
dictionary_name.get('value',dictionary_name.get('intValue'))
```

more than two possible key then: (**First value will be 1st priority!**)

```
d.get('value',d.get('intValue',d.get(.......)))
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to mark this as helpful yet, but this is extremely helpful. I think it will work for the example I posted. I found another, more complex log format, so I am going to try to use this against that. Will post an update. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I hope I've understood you correctly:

```py
lst = [
    {"kind": "admin#reports#activity", "other_key": 1},
    {"name": "api_name", "value": "caldav", "other_key": 2},
    {"name": "other_name", "intValue": 999, "other_key": 3},
]

for d in lst:
    if "kind" not in d:
        d[d.pop("name")] = d.pop("value") if "value" in d else d.pop("intValue")

print(lst)
```

will transform the `lst` to:

```py
[
    {"kind": "admin#reports#activity", "other_key": 1},
    {"other_key": 2, "api_name": "caldav"},
    {"other_key": 3, "other_name": 999},
]
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to mark this as helpful, but I greatly appreciate the response. I will try it out tomorrow!

Comment: isn't `out` list superfluous here, since you are modifying the dicts of original `lst` in place

Comment: @Anentropic Yes, good point... I'll remove it for clarity